# What does Demeter mean in Law Of Demeter

Tags: oop

What is the **Demeter** mean in Law of Demeter?
why does it stands for Least Knowledge Principle as it's Greek goddess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a project (in 1987) named "Demeter" at the Northeastern University in Boston. It concerned itself with a hardware description language named "Zeus", and that is how they came up with the name "Demeter" (Zeus' sister).

Within this project, the "Law of Demeter" was being coined.

(Source: [Wikipedia.DE on Law of Demeter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesetz_von_Demeter) referring to http://www.bradapp.com/docs/demeter-intro.html)